# AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)----Error message in new Eclipse enviornment

Tags: android, exception, filenotfoundexception

Forum-

After an importing a previously working package into my Eclipse IDE All of my packages started producing errors specifically about not being able to find the native library directory that contained the "ANDROID_FRAMEWORK".  After some tinkering I decided that the best thing would be to start again and do a clean install of the IDE.  I followed Google's instructions for installation

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Using the latest Helios version of Eclipse.  I created a new directory and workspace, linking to none of the resources from my old IDE in fact I trashed all of it before reinstalling.

I created a new "hello world" project to test the install. Upon creation the new package threw the following error.

"Unable to read /Developer_Android/Android-sdk/AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Developer_Android/Android-sdk/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)"

Now this is what I was encountering before as well. This being a new install though I do not know what could be causing this. Unless there is some resource OUTSIDE the eclipse folder that is setting a preference that I inadvertently changed and remains intact after my deletion of the previous IDE.

Any Clarity anyone can lend to this situation would be helpful since all dev work is FULL STOP.

Cheers,

Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not sure if this will help, but it may be worth trying:

right-click project -> android tools -> fix project properties

Comment: Ok.  I did a clean install and tried again this time though I saw that there is a hidden directory named ".android" in the /Users directory. I found it:
find . -name '*.android'
and then I deleted the directory:

rm -r .android <----be VERY careful when using this command

Answer (score 3):

I saw that there is a hidden directory named ".android" in the /Users directory. Using Terminal I found it: 
find . -name '*.android' 
and then I deleted the directory: 
rm -r .android <----be VERY careful when using this command

Once I deleted that I was able to do a clean install and run Google's Hello World.  When I imported I had a "Compiler Compliance" error. Opening the Java compiler in the packages property seemed to fix this and all packages are importing without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well after doing a bunch of SDK and plugin version updates.

I tried the "right-click project -> android tools -> fix project properties" as suggested by Ian, but that didn't help in my case anyway.

I found the hidden directory .android in my $HOME (/Users/username) but not in my /Users directory (from bklynjones answer). To be safer, I did a 'mv .android .androidREMOVE'. I want ahead and restarted eclipse although I'm not sure if that was totally necessary. My app is working now!