# Android studio cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, android-activity

```
Error:Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
G:\milestone\FunYou\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Please post snapshot.

Comment: right-click project -> android tools -> fix project properties

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247368/androidmanifest-xml-no-such-file-or-directory-error-message-in-new-eclipse

Comment: G:\milestone\Funou\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified) this is error and how can i resolve it

Comment: Sync project with gradle file and. Try steps of menue build -> clean project. After that build ->  rebuild project

Answer (score 2):

Follow these 3 steps to solve this problem-

1) Right Click The Project.

2) Click on Android Tools.

3) Fix Project Properties.

Refer to this page if you didn't get the answer :
 [AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)----Error message in new Eclipse enviornment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247368/androidmanifest-xml-no-such-file-or-directory-error-message-in-new-eclipse)

Comment: but am using android studio

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I solved the problem changing the path of my ANDROID_HOME environment variable. It was wrong!!!
Make sure that the path points to your android sdk location, for default the path is something like this:
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

I also updated my "path" system variable adding these two paths:
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\plataforms
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\plataform-tools